# Match repeating characters from set

Tags: python, regex, string

```
from re import search
import random
while True:
    r = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 100)))
    if search('[0-9a-f]{5,}', r):
        print('Found')
```

Is it possible to match exactly one repeating character from set `[0-9a-f]` so it only matches cases like `44444` or `aaaaaaa` but does not matches cases with random chars like `bc657ff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capture group and backreference to do something like this:

```
if search(r'([0-9a-f])\1{4,}', r):
    print('Found')
```

Here, `([0-9a-f])` the parens indicate that the first match is stored into the first capture group. `\1` then is the backreference that refers to that first capture group, after which `{4,}` repeats that captured group at least 4 times (the first time has already been matched, so you need to minus 1 from the 5).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Sorry ^^;

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Very true. I tend to forget that when I type the explanation =/ Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry : You're allowed to test the code in your answer before posting. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring After doing that so many times, I tend to think it automagically works without testing; I know it's bad, but sometimes single lines like that escape the control test :s

Comment: @Jerry : Murphy's Law says that when you don't test you're bound to muck it up. :) For little bits of code like that, it's easy enough to test in the interactive interpreter so you don't accidentally do something silly. FWIW, I follow the doc's recommendation to _always_ use a raw string for regexes, even when it's not necessary, just so I don't forget it when the string contains backslashes.

Comment: @PM2Ring True that, I take the responsibility of messing up, I'm lazy and don't deny it lol. Well, lazy sometimes. And I raw my regex as well when I use them, and that might be why I overlooked it. My mind sees all regex rawed by default =/. I really didn't notice the regex string wasn't rawed until it was pointed out.